# Installing Ajenti fails because of python dependencies which aren't found

Tags: python, centos5

I'm trying to install Ajenti http://ajenti.org
I've followed the instructions on their website but when I do:

```
yum install ajenti
```

I get this:

```
python26-greenlet-0.3.4-trunk.i386 from ajenti has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libpython2.6.so.1.0 is needed by package python26-greenlet-    0.3.4-trunk.i386 (ajenti)
python26-gevent-1.0b2-trunk.i386 from ajenti has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libpython2.6.so.1.0 is needed by package python26-gevent-1.0b2-    trunk.i386 (ajenti)
python26-lxml-2.3.3-2.i386 from ajenti has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libpython2.6.so.1.0 is needed by package python26-lxml-2.3.3-2.i386 (ajenti)
ajenti-0.6.2-1.noarch from ajenti has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: /usr/bin/python26 is needed by package ajenti-0.6.2-1.noarch   (ajenti)
ajenti-0.6.2-1.noarch from ajenti has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: python26 is needed by package ajenti-0.6.2-1.noarch (ajenti)
Error: Missing Dependency: libpython2.6.so.1.0 is needed by package python26-lxml- 2.3.3-2.i386 (ajenti)
Error: Missing Dependency: python26 is needed by package ajenti-0.6.2-1.noarch (ajenti)
Error: Missing Dependency: libpython2.6.so.1.0 is needed by package python26-greenlet-   0.3.4-trunk.i386 (ajenti)
Error: Missing Dependency: libpython2.6.so.1.0 is needed by package python26-gevent-  1.0b2-trunk.i386 (ajenti)
Error: Missing Dependency: /usr/bin/python26 is needed by package ajenti-0.6.2-1.noarch    (ajenti)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base CentOS 5 system includes Python 2.4, whereas Ajenti requires Python 2.6. Python 2.6 is however available in the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository, so you need to [configure this](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F) before installing Ajenti.

Comment: Yeh i've installed python 2.6.7 Because when I do Python -V it says 2.6.7. Didnt install it with the EPEL repos though. I shall try it that way and let you know if it worked :)

Comment: @mattyh88 If you didn't install it using packages (using the same scheme as EPEL) then the dependencies aren't going to be met.

Comment: thx! It's working now :)